# Anyone know how to fix this scrolling bug in the VSCode python test explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

[Here's a link to a gif of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aQUJ.jpg)

My problem is that I have a large batch of unit tests, many of which are out of date and need fixing. If I try and just run 1 specific unit test, the test explorer will run that test correctly, but will do massive amounts of scrolling and lose its place.

Note: In the gif it happens when I click the run button for the specific test, but it also happens if I click the CodeLens in the code itself.